# Rails: Bitly invalid uri error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to use the `gem "bitly"` to shorten a link in my rails app. But it gives me an error `INVALID_URI - '500'`

```
def show
  @product = Product.find(params[:id])
  bitly = Bitly.new('my-user-name','my-api-key')
  page_url = bitly.shorten(request.original_url)
  @url = page_url.short_url
end
```

request.original_url = `http://localhost:3000/products/219`

This works:  `bitly.shorten("http://www.google.com")`

but this doesn't: `bitly.shorten("http://localhost:3000/products/219")`

Any clue why?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

So it turns out that you cannot bitly a localhost link. When you launch your app that code would most likely work.

Answer (score 0):

@Cauterise is correct - I had the same issue. Worked on heroku when I pushed it; however, still would render the error page on local. To eliminate the local error, just wrap the bitly code in an if statement:

```
if Rails.env.development?
  ‘foobar’
else
  do_url_shortener
end
```